# C# Event handler Behavior

Tags: c#, .net, events

I have this code

```
List<DaSubscription> lstSubscription=new List<DaSubscription>();

for(int i=0;i<20;i++)//20 is just to simulate the behavior
{

    DaSubscription Generic=new DaSubscription();
    Generic.DataChanged += new DataChangedEventHandler(Generic_DataChanged);
    lstSubscription.add(Generic);
}

//EVENT Handler which is raised from a 3rd party library [COM]                 

void Generic_DataChanged(DaSubscription aDaSubscription, DaItem[] items, ValueQT[] values, int[] results)
{
   UpdateDataChangedDTO(items, values);
}
```

As the same event handler [m_daSubscription_Generic_DataChanged] is assigned to the multiple instance of same class [m_daSubscription]. Question i have is if at the same time multiple instances invokes this handler how will be handled here. will there will be any instance it shall overwrite the data. or the event handler will be separate for each instance.

Comment: Please *please* start following normal .NET naming conventions. Using `m_daSubscription` is bad enough for variables IMO, but as a *type* name?

Comment: You need more code, frankly, to show us what you're trying to do.  What does `UpdateDataChangedDTO` **do** here?  Why do you `-=` and `+=` the same event?  What's the magic number `20` for?  Also: the naming conventions serve to confuse things - please rename them to make things clearer, so we can understand without having to struggle through the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event handlers execute seperately.  It sounds like your worried about the parameters being overwritten by another call to the handler.  That won't happen (I don't think it is even possible). Since it doesn't look like you are accessing any shared objects in the event handler, you should be perfectly safe.